# Restoring Saved Webpages on Home Screen from Backup

Tags: itunes, ipad, icloud, backup, data-recovery

I ran into an update issue with my iPad, and took it to the Apple store to fix it. When I got there, an employee said that I could only recover from the issue by resetting my iPad. After he reset it, it was left in the 'new' state. I managed to restore my information from a backup that was made a few months back, but one of the most important things that wasn't restored were a large number of Safari webpages saved to the homescreen, organized into sub-folders, etc. These represent quite a large time investment to manually restore, and it may be impossible for me to do so from memory.

I read through [this post about restoring additional information through an iTunes re-sync](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/49320/itunes-refuses-to-restore-home-screen-arrangement-from-backup), but I'm not sure that the linked scenario applies here, and I don't have a device to test this with.

I tried reaching out to Apple support / the Apple store, but they could not or would not help me.

Any help that you could provide to restore these saved webpages would be incredibly appreciated! :)

Answer (score 1):

**For a restore to work, the data must be backed up in the first place.**

> I managed to restore my information from a backup that was made a few months back, but one of the most important things that wasn't restored were a large number of Safari webpages saved to the home screen

The critical piece here is,  was all that work you did backed up at any point?  If the last backup was made "a few months back," you won't be able to restore anything since because it simply doesn't exist. From what you describe, it wasn't backed up.

Unfortunately, nobody is going to be able to assist as you've found with your latest interaction with Apple.  You will have to re-create it from memory.

Comment: I may not have been clear, but yes, > 90% of the saved webpages were present when the backup in question was made, and most would have been there for months/years by that point.